# Updating inventory quantity

Tags: shopify

If I set some product/variant with the following options:

- Inventory: Shopify tracks this variant's stock level
- How many are in Stock: 9 (for example)
- and "I Allow users to purchase this item, even if it is no longer in stock" selected

When I receive an order, Shopify reduces my stock (and I did not fulfill the items, I did not accept the payment).

Is possible decrease my stock when I fulfill the items? or manage the stock manually?

Thanks in advance

Berins

Answer (score 0):

You could just set the stock to 0 and manage the value externally if you wanted. Shopify will always reduce the stock as soon as the order is created, if the order is later cancelled the stock will be returned. There is no way to change it so tha stock is reduced only when an item is fulfilled.